# Finding indirect neighbors in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

Consider this dataset:

```
                      Vertex                                                                                 Neighbors
1                      MUJAO                                                                   CMA, Government of Mali
2                        CMA MUJAO, Ansar Dine, Government of Mali, MAA, GATIA, MSA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, CM-FPR
3                 Ansar Dine                                                                   CMA, Government of Mali
4         Government of Mali      MUJAO, CMA, Ansar Dine, IS, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, JNIM
5                        MAA                                                                                       CMA
6               Dozos (Mali)                                                                                      JNIM
7                      GATIA                                                                                   CMA, IS
8                        MSA                                                                                   CMA, IS
```

I want to find indrect neighbors. So actors that share the same neighbor without beeing an neighbors. Further i want to find actors that share at least two neighbors without beeing an neighbor itself. I know something can be done using the  `igraph` package, but I am looking for a solution outside network analysis.

here is replicable data:

```
structure(list(Vertex = c("MUJAO", "CMA", "Ansar Dine", "Government of Mali", 
"MAA", "Dozos (Mali)", "GATIA", "MSA", "IS", "Dan na Ambassagou", 
"Signed-in-Blood Battalion", "AQIM", "al-Murabitun", "FLM", "CM-FPR", 
"JNIM"), Neighbors = c("CMA, Government of Mali", "MUJAO, Ansar Dine, Government of Mali, MAA, GATIA, MSA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, CM-FPR", 
"CMA, Government of Mali", "MUJAO, CMA, Ansar Dine, IS, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, JNIM", 
"CMA", "JNIM", "CMA, IS", "CMA, IS", "Government of Mali, GATIA, MSA, JNIM", 
"JNIM", "CMA, Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
"Government of Mali", "CMA", "Government of Mali, Dozos (Mali), IS, Dan na Ambassagou"
)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

I came up with this, but I am open for further approaches:

```
find_allies <- function(vertex_index, data) {
  current_vertex <- data$Vertex[vertex_index]
  current_neighbors <- unlist(strsplit(data$Neighbors[vertex_index], ",\\s*"))
  allies <- c()
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    if (i != vertex_index) {
      other_neighbors <- unlist(strsplit(data$Neighbors[i], ",\\s*"))
      if (!identical(current_neighbors, other_neighbors) &&
          length(intersect(current_neighbors, other_neighbors)) > 0 &&
          !current_vertex %in% other_neighbors &&
          !data$Vertex[i] %in% current_neighbors) {
        allies <- c(allies, data$Vertex[i])
      }
    }
  }
  
  return(paste(allies, collapse = ", "))
}


data$Allies <- sapply(1:nrow(data), function(x) find_allies(x, data))


print(data)
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: *but I am looking for a solution outside network analysis.* Why?

Comment: To be honest, I do not have that much experience using network analysis

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this outside igraph, indirect neighbors are broadly equivalent to inner joins on a long version of the Vertex/Neighbors data with subsequent filtering.

```
tmp <- data.frame(
  Vertex = c("MUJAO", "CMA", "Ansar Dine", "Government of Mali", 
             "MAA", "Dozos (Mali)", "GATIA", "MSA", "IS", "Dan na Ambassagou", 
             "Signed-in-Blood Battalion", "AQIM", "al-Murabitun", 
             "FLM", "CM-FPR", "JNIM"), 
  Neighbors = c(
    "CMA, Government of Mali", 
    "MUJAO, Ansar Dine, Government of Mali, MAA, GATIA, MSA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, CM-FPR", 
    "CMA, Government of Mali", 
    "MUJAO, CMA, Ansar Dine, IS, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, JNIM", 
    "CMA", "JNIM", "CMA, IS", "CMA, IS", "Government of Mali, GATIA, MSA, JNIM", 
    "JNIM", "CMA, Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", "Government of Mali", 
    "Government of Mali", "CMA", "Government of Mali, Dozos (Mali), IS, Dan na Ambassagou"
  ))

library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

# Create a long data set
tmp_long <- separate_rows(tmp, Neighbors, sep = ',')

# Convert to data.table
setDT(tmp_long)
setorder(tmp_long, Vertex, Neighbors)

# Find vertices which share neighbors (deduplicated)
indirect <- tmp_long[tmp_long, on = .(Neighbors), allow.cartesian = TRUE][Vertex < i.Vertex]

# Drop any rows which are already neighbors
indirect[tmp_long, are_neighbors := 1, on = .(Vertex, i.Vertex = Neighbors)]
indirect <- indirect[is.na(are_neighbors)]

# Make sure they have at least two common neighbors
indirect[, count := .N, by = .(Vertex, i.Vertex)]
indirect[count >= 2, .(neighbour_count = .N,
                       neighbors = paste(Neighbors, collapse = ',')), 
         keyby = .(Vertex, i.Vertex)]
```

And the results

```
       Vertex                  i.Vertex neighbour_count                                    neighbors
1: Ansar Dine                     MUJAO               2                       Government of Mali,CMA
2: Ansar Dine Signed-in-Blood Battalion               2                       Government of Mali,CMA
3:        CMA        Government of Mali               3  Ansar Dine, Signed-in-Blood Battalion,MUJAO
4:        CMA                        IS               2                                   GATIA, MSA
5:      GATIA                       MSA               2                                       IS,CMA
6:      MUJAO Signed-in-Blood Battalion               2                       Government of Mali,CMA
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what is the reason that prevents you using network analysis method, but it is worthwhile to take a look how network analysis simplifies your work

```
g <- df %>%
  separate_longer_delim(Neighbors, delim = ", ") %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(FALSE) %>%
  simplify()


nb2 <- g %>%
  ego(order = 2, mindist = 2)


dfout <- df %>%
  mutate(
    IndNeighbors = {
      nb2 %>%
        map(\(x) toString(names(x))) %>%
        setNames(names((V(g)))) %>%
        unlist()
    }[Vertex],
    AtLeast2CommonIndirectNeighbor = setNames(
      lapply(
        1:vcount(g),
        \(k) {
          u <- nb2[[k]]
          toString(
            names(u)[mapply(
              \(...) length(intersect(...)) > 1,
              ego(g, nodes = u, mindist = 1),
              ego(g, nodes = V(g)[k], mindist = 1)
            )]
          )
        }
      ), names(V(g))
    )[Vertex]
  )
```

and you will obtain

```
                      Vertex
1                      MUJAO
2                        CMA
3                 Ansar Dine
4         Government of Mali
5                        MAA
6               Dozos (Mali)
7                      GATIA
8                        MSA
9                         IS
10         Dan na Ambassagou
11 Signed-in-Blood Battalion
12                      AQIM
13              al-Murabitun
14                       FLM
15                    CM-FPR
16                      JNIM
                                                                                   Neighbors
1                                                                    CMA, Government of Mali
2  MUJAO, Ansar Dine, Government of Mali, MAA, GATIA, MSA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, CM-FPR
3                                                                    CMA, Government of Mali
4       MUJAO, CMA, Ansar Dine, IS, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, JNIM
5                                                                                        CMA
6                                                                                       JNIM
7                                                                                    CMA, IS
8                                                                                    CMA, IS
9                                                       Government of Mali, GATIA, MSA, JNIM
10                                                                                      JNIM
11                                                                   CMA, Government of Mali
12                                                                        Government of Mali
13                                                                        Government of Mali
14                                                                        Government of Mali
15                                                                                       CMA
16                                   Government of Mali, Dozos (Mali), IS, Dan na Ambassagou
                                                                                                  IndNeighbors
1            Ansar Dine, MAA, GATIA, MSA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, CM-FPR, IS, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, JNIM
2                                                                            IS, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, JNIM
3                 MUJAO, MAA, GATIA, MSA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, CM-FPR, IS, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, JNIM
4                                                     MAA, GATIA, MSA, CM-FPR, Dozos (Mali), Dan na Ambassagou
5                         MUJAO, Ansar Dine, Government of Mali, GATIA, MSA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, CM-FPR
6                                                                    Government of Mali, IS, Dan na Ambassagou
7                     MUJAO, Ansar Dine, Government of Mali, MAA, MSA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, CM-FPR, JNIM
8                   MUJAO, Ansar Dine, Government of Mali, MAA, GATIA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, CM-FPR, JNIM
9  MUJAO, CMA, Ansar Dine, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, Dozos (Mali), Dan na Ambassagou
10                                                                        Government of Mali, Dozos (Mali), IS
11                               MUJAO, Ansar Dine, MAA, GATIA, MSA, CM-FPR, IS, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, JNIM
12                              MUJAO, CMA, Ansar Dine, IS, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, al-Murabitun, FLM, JNIM
13                                      MUJAO, CMA, Ansar Dine, IS, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, AQIM, FLM, JNIM
14                             MUJAO, CMA, Ansar Dine, IS, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, AQIM, al-Murabitun, JNIM
15                           MUJAO, Ansar Dine, Government of Mali, MAA, GATIA, MSA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion
16                      MUJAO, CMA, Ansar Dine, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, GATIA, MSA
          AtLeast2CommonIndirectNeighbor
1  Ansar Dine, Signed-in-Blood Battalion
2                                     IS
3       MUJAO, Signed-in-Blood Battalion
4                             GATIA, MSA
5
6
7                Government of Mali, MSA
8              Government of Mali, GATIA
9                                    CMA
10
11                     MUJAO, Ansar Dine
12
13
14
15
16
```

where the last two columns might be the things you are after

```
> dfout[-c(1:2)]
                                                                                                  IndNeighbors
1            Ansar Dine, MAA, GATIA, MSA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, CM-FPR, IS, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, JNIM
2                                                                            IS, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, JNIM
3                 MUJAO, MAA, GATIA, MSA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, CM-FPR, IS, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, JNIM
4                                                     MAA, GATIA, MSA, CM-FPR, Dozos (Mali), Dan na Ambassagou
5                         MUJAO, Ansar Dine, Government of Mali, GATIA, MSA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, CM-FPR
6                                                                    Government of Mali, IS, Dan na Ambassagou
7                     MUJAO, Ansar Dine, Government of Mali, MAA, MSA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, CM-FPR, JNIM
8                   MUJAO, Ansar Dine, Government of Mali, MAA, GATIA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, CM-FPR, JNIM
9  MUJAO, CMA, Ansar Dine, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, Dozos (Mali), Dan na Ambassagou
10                                                                        Government of Mali, Dozos (Mali), IS
11                               MUJAO, Ansar Dine, MAA, GATIA, MSA, CM-FPR, IS, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, JNIM
12                              MUJAO, CMA, Ansar Dine, IS, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, al-Murabitun, FLM, JNIM
13                                      MUJAO, CMA, Ansar Dine, IS, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, AQIM, FLM, JNIM
14                             MUJAO, CMA, Ansar Dine, IS, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, AQIM, al-Murabitun, JNIM
15                           MUJAO, Ansar Dine, Government of Mali, MAA, GATIA, MSA, Signed-in-Blood Battalion
16                      MUJAO, CMA, Ansar Dine, Signed-in-Blood Battalion, AQIM, al-Murabitun, FLM, GATIA, MSA
          AtLeast2CommonIndirectNeighbor
1  Ansar Dine, Signed-in-Blood Battalion
2                                     IS
3       MUJAO, Signed-in-Blood Battalion
4                             GATIA, MSA
5
6
7                Government of Mali, MSA
8              Government of Mali, GATIA
9                                    CMA
10
11                     MUJAO, Ansar Dine
12
13
14
15
16
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, "Further I want to find actors that share at least two neighbors without beeing an neighbor itself " is not achieved via your approach.